# How to pass UIViewController to another class in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

How to pass UIViewController to another class in Swift?
I have `SomeViewController` class:

```
class RidingViewController: UIViewController {
    fileprivate let header = RidingViewHeader(controller: self)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        header.setNavigationBar()
    }
    ...
}
```

And I want to separate some code and to set up its header in the another class. I've created this class

```
class RidingViewHeader {

    var controller: UIViewController
    let navigationBar= UINavigationBar()
    let navigationItem = UINavigationItem()

    init(controller: UIViewController) {
        self.controller = controller
    }
    ...
}
```

In this case I get an error:
`Cannot convert value of type '(NSObject) -> () -> UIViewController' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'`

What is the better way of doing it?

Comment: In which line do you get that, is it in `fileprivate let header = RidingViewHeader(controller: self)`?

Comment: @EmilioPelaez yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't access `self` until the view controller has been initialized. You could make it a lazy variable:

```
fileprivate lazy var header: RidingViewHeader = {
    return RidingViewHeader(controller: self)
}()
```

Comment: Thanks, now I see where the problem was